# Вид предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

Можно считать выделенное предложение изъяснительным или требуется  наличие "что"?

> Он знал: **ни один и ни другой ему не соперники**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны **два варианта**:

1) Изъяснительные отношения между предложениями в составе БСП (бессоюзное предложение):  **Он знал: ни один и ни другой ему не соперники.**

2) СПП (сложноподчиненное предложение) с придаточным изъяснительным: **Он знал, что ни один и ни другой ему не соперники. ЧТО ― союз.**